# Simple css for 3 equal rows per line doesn't work

Tags: html, css

I have simple flex rows which I'm trying to line them on one line but for some reason it doesn't work. They are one under another.

I have created demo here:

https://jsfiddle.net/L2xor1jf/1/

```css
    .page-content {
        max-width: 1366px;
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: 10%;
        padding-top: 50px;
    }
    section {
       display: block;
    }
    .flex-container{
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        -webkit-box-pack: center;
        -ms-flex-pack: center;
      justify-content: center;
     
    }
    .flex-container>div {
      flex-basis:30%;
      margin:5px;
     
    }
```

```html
<section class="page-content">
      
    <div id="site-main">
      <div class="flex-container">
         <div class="container box">
          <div class="item">
           <p class="headline font--h5 accent--teal">Title title</p>
           <div class="fullwidth">
                      
           </div>
           <div class="font--h5 body body--dark">
            Some text
           </div>
          </div>
          <p class="read-more"><a href="">Read More</a></p>
         </div>
      
    </div> 
         
    </div>
    
    </section>
```

Comment: Shouldn't your `.flex-container` have `display: flex`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you forgot `display: flex`.

```
.flex-container{
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Edit: An explanation... You need the display property to define the container as a flexbox and that is what tells the children of that element that they should use a flex context.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Strange but on the fiddle is working but on the page doesn't work.

Comment: I don't know what browser you're using, but maybe check to see if you're using the appropriate [prefix](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)? (edited to add a better link)

Comment: Or are you using external links, external libraries containing CSS on the page that you didn't include in the fiddle? Classes like `font--h5` sound like they're part of a framework.

Answer (score 2):

Your flex container is missing the flex style

```css
.page-content {
    max-width: 1366px;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: 10%;
    padding-top: 50px;
}
section {
   display: block;
}
.flex-container{
    -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    -webkit-box-pack: center;
    -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display:flex;

}
.flex-container>div {
  flex-basis:30%;
  margin:5px;

}
```

```html
<section class="page-content">
  
<div id="site-main">
  <div class="flex-container">
     <div class="container box">
      <div class="item">
       <p class="headline font--h5 accent--teal">Title title</p>
       <div class="fullwidth">
                  
       </div>
       <div class="font--h5 body body--dark">
        Some text
       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="read-more"><a href="">Read More</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="container box">
      <div class="item">
       <p class="headline font--h5 accent--teal">Title title</p>
       <div class="fullwidth">
                  
       </div>
       <div class="font--h5 body body--dark">
        Some text
       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="read-more"><a href="">Read More</a></p>
     </div>
     <div class="container box">
      <div class="item">
       <p class="headline font--h5 accent--teal">Title title</p>
       <div class="fullwidth">
                  
       </div>
       <div class="font--h5 body body--dark">
        Some text
       </div>
      </div>
      <p class="read-more"><a href="">Read More</a></p>
     </div>          
</div> 
     
</div>

</section>
```

Comment: Then the problem is with something else. When I add images and text they become one under another. Everything is the same. I just add image, title and excerpt..